# How to get jQuery multiselect values on the server side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm using the following jquery [multiselect plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) ... How can I grab the selected values server side via asp.net mvc3 within the [HttpPost] ActionResult()?

Comment: You can collect the values in a string and split them server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request["FormElementName"]

Will come through as a comma separated list.

Or if it's in your model you can acccess it via model.FormElementName which would come through as a array of strings or integers depending on your datatype.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  This worked perfect with comma delimited string.

Answer (score 1):

You can just have an array as a parameter of your controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(string[] nameOfMultiSelect)
{
    ....
}
```